# Sum of data in multiple rows that echo with GROUP_CONCAT in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have a data set generated with CodeIgniter using MySQL. I need to get **Total Delivered Qty** in the view page. For that I used the following code.

```
 <?php $delivered_qty_total += $row->quantity; endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

But it did not give the accurate total of the **Delivered Qty**. I am passing data with  `GROUP_CONCAT` with `SEPARATOR "<br />"`.When I am using  `tbl_order_products.quantity` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT` it give me the accurate total. but I need it with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
'GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_order_products.quantity SEPARATOR "<br />" ) as quantity ',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your query:

```
SUM(tbl_order_product.quantity) AS quantity_total
```

[**See this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beecf/1) for a example of how I see this working for you.

Comment: Thank you @Mark M you save my time :)